# How to modify a JavaScript RegExp pattern

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to create a new `RegExp` object by *modifying* the pattern from another `RegExp` object.

The output of [`RegExp.prototype.toString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/toString) includes leading and trailing slashes.

```
    // This is nice and clean, but produces incorrect output.
    function addBarWrong(re) {
            return new RegExp(re+"bar");
    }

    addBarWrong(new RegExp("foo")); // -> /\/foo\/bar/
```

My naive approach is pretty inelegant.

```
    // This is unpleasant to look at, but produces correct output.
    function addBarUgly(re) {
            var reString = re.toString();

            reString = reString.substr(1, reString.length - 2);

            return new RegExp(reString+"bar");
    }

    addBarUgly(new RegExp("foo")); // -> /foobar/
```

Surely there's a better way. What is the clean solution here?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use the [`source`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/source) (Luke) property.

```js
function addBarElegant(re) {
  var reString = re.source;
  return new RegExp(reString + "bar", re.flags);
}
console.log(addBarElegant(/foo/));
```

Comment: Would we be complete with `new RegExp(re.source, re.flags)`?